# Why form redirects and not only "process" data?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, axios

There is a `form` here. Earlier I always used `axios`, anyway. So a `POST` is sent to `https://api.skymongoose.com/subscription` after subscribe button is pressed.

But why it redirects to a blank website? Url points to `https://api.skymongoose.com/subscription`.

```js
<section className="section-base align-center section-color">
                <div className="container">
                    <h2>Feliratkozom most</h2>
                    <div className="width-650">
                        <p>Kíváncsi vagyok mi történik felétek</p>
                        <hr className="space-sm" />
                        <form
                            action="https://api.skymongoose.com/subscription"
                            className="form-box form-ajax form-inline align-center"
                            method="post"
                            data-email="example@domain.com"
                        >
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-4"></div>
```

Comment: How is that "ajax"? It's just a form.

Comment: ahh, ok, I thought the class `form-ajax` represent something, but maybe not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don’t override it using JavaScript, submitting the form will bundle the data in the form into an HTTP request, send that request to the url in the `action` and navigate to the result (rendering it in the viewport) much like a link (with a more complicated request).

If `https://api.skymongoose.com/subscription` doesn’t display anything useful then it probably isn’t designed to be accessed with a regular form submission.